# Questions on sqlite transactions

Tags: sqlite, transactions

1) Is it ok to do inserts,deletes and updates in one transaction?
2) Is there a (recommended) limit to the number of writes per transaction?

Comment: till now, did'nt find any issue in inserts,deletes and updates in one transaction

Comment: I've tried it too.. I had no problems... But transaction suggestions were like `group your inserts`.. So I had a doubt if it is right different writes on one transaction.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction is a logical block. You can do whatever you want within one transaction.

For example, for one functions  of our product we build a temporary table, insert a set of tuples there and then run a `SELECT` that uses that temporary table and a permanent table. All that stuff is inside a transaction which is rolled back afterwards so that no changes happen to the database.